# R training and tuning random forest classifier with hardware challenge

Tags: r, random-forest, hardware, r-caret, multilabel-classification

I'm sorry if this is not appropriate to ask here but please forgive a noobie.
I'm training a random forest multiple class(8) classifier using R Caret on my experimental data using my desktop, 32GB RAM and a 4 core CPU. However, I'm facing constant complains from RStudio reporting  it cannot allocate vector of 9GB. So I have to reduce the training set all the way to 1% of the data just to run fold CV and some grid search. As a result my mode accuracy is ~50% and the resulting features selected aren't very good at all. Only 2 out of 8 classes are being distinguished somewhat truthfully. Of course it could be that I don't have any good features. But I want to at least test train and tune my model on a decent size of training data first. What are the solutions can help? or is there anywhere I can upload my data and train somewhere? I'm so new that I don't know if something like cloud based things can help me? Pointers will be appreciated.

Edit: I have uploaded the data table and my codes so maybe it is my bad coding screwed things up.

Here is a link to the data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wScYKd7J-KlRvvDxHAmG3_If1o5yUimy/view?usp=sharing

Here are my codes:

```
#load libraries
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(caTools)
library(e1071)

#read the data in
df.raw <-fread("CLL_merged_sampled_same_ctrl_40percent.csv", header =TRUE,data.table = FALSE)
#get the useful data
#subset and get rid of useless labels
df.1 <- subset(df.raw, select = c(18:131))
df <- subset(df.1, select = -c(2:4))

#As I want to build a RF model to classify drug treatments
# make the treatmentsun as factors
#there should be 7 levels
df$treatmentsum <- as.factor(df$treatmentsum)
df$treatmentsum

#find nearZerovarance features
#I did not remove them. Just flagged them
nzv <- nearZeroVar(df[-1], saveMetrics= TRUE)
nzv[nzv$nzv==TRUE,]
possible.nzv.flagged <- nzv[nzv$nzv=="TRUE",]
write.csv(possible.nzv.flagged, "Near Zero Features flagged.CSV", row.names = TRUE)


 #identify correlated features
 df.Cor <- cor(df[-1])
 highCorr <- sum(abs(df.Cor[upper.tri(df.Cor)]) > .99)
 highlyCor <- findCorrelation(df.Cor, cutoff = .99,verbose = TRUE)

 #Get rid off strongly correlated features
 filtered.df<- df[ ,-highlyCor]

 str(filtered.df)
 #identify linear dependecies

 linear.combo <- findLinearCombos(filtered.df[-1])
 linear.combo #no linear ones detected

 #splt datainto training and test
 #Here is my problem, I want to use 80% of the data for training
 #but in my computer, I can only use 0.002

 set.seed(123)
 split <- sample.split(filtered.df$treatmentsum, SplitRatio = 0.8)
 training_set <- subset(filtered.df, split==TRUE)
 test_set <- subset(filtered.df, split==FALSE)

 #scaling numeric data
 #leave the first column labels out

 training_set[-1] = scale(training_set[-1])
 test_set[-1] = scale(test_set[-1])
 training_set[1]


 #build RF
 #use Cross validation for model training
 #I can't use repeated CV as it fails on my machine
 #I set a grid search for tuning

 control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10,verboseIter = TRUE, search = 'grid')

 #default mtry below, is around 10
 #mtry <- sqrt(ncol(training_set))
 #I used ,mtry 1:12 to run, but I wanted to test more, limited again by machine  

 tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = (1:20))
 model <- train(training_set[,-1],as.factor(training_set[,1]), data=training_set, method = "rf", trControl = control,metric= "Accuracy", maximize = TRUE ,importance = TRUE, type="classification", ntree =800,tuneGrid = tunegrid)

  print(model)
  plot(model)

  prediction2 <- predict(model, test_set[,-1])

  cm<-confusionMatrix(prediction2, as.factor(test_set[,1]),  positive = "1")
```

Comment: How big is your dataset? It could be that it's just too large to be loaded into memory (hence the 9GB vector allocation issue). I don't know if the [`bigmemory` package](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/temp/bigmemory-vignette.pdf) will be of help here, but might be worth taking a look at. Also look at [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41/is-the-r-language-suitable-for-big-data) and [this](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/07/17/3-big-data-strategies-for-r/).

Comment: you can try using ```ranger```, although most likely with caret, it might not help that much with the memory. there is a save.memory option in ranger

Comment: @Dunois  hi guys, thank you for getting back to me. The data files where I sample ~40 % of raw data and bind them into the sample data is ~2.5GB CSV, 2,222,259 rows and 106 observations/features, across 8 treatments (aka true data label). I think the problem might be in the trainControl that with multiple class the data got blow up?

Comment: Acutally I'm so dumb, let me just upload the data and my code, see if it is actually my code has a problem

Comment: @StupidWolf now I hope this edit help to explain myself

Comment: @Dunois now the edited version is ready. Do you mind have a look at my code and data so I know whether I do have a machine hardware issue or im just bad at coding?

Comment: @ML33M I would suggest you remove the link to your data, lest it get misused by somebody. This sort of massive data stuff isn't my area of specialty, but I'll give this a try and report back here.

Comment: @Dunois thank you. But if I remove the link, how do I share my data with people here? Is there a better way for data this size?

Comment: I think it's best if you share it on a need-to-use basis. That looks like research data (Fluorescence microscopy? Cell cytometry?), and I presume the loss/theft of that data far outweighs the value of having it processed expeditiously?

Comment: @Dunois Yes you are right, this is a very small part of my data, extracted from microscopy images. I took this small part out of the data file for model training and learning, and I think having this datatable wont mean anything to anyone else but me who have the other few TB test data and context. hence why I did it. Your concern is a great point, I would love to see if there's any good platform that I can use for need-to-use basis?

Comment: My suggestion is: ranger, mlr3 with data base backend and subsampling + averaging of models: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/backends.html. Read the whole book.in case this sounds interesting.

Comment: @missuse thank you. I will have a read now.

Comment: With this constraint in mind, you might want to build multiple RF models based on random subsets of the data, and then take an ensemble average for the prediction. This has been shown to work with reasonably well for many use cases https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7502

Comment: @RobertWilson thank you for the suggestion, I will have a read and try to code this. damn I wish I'm good at this.